# Hyperledger Fabric Bluemix cp-web us.blockchain.ibm.com.cert unknown authority

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

The application has been running fine on Bluemix for several months. Then it stopped accepting logins. I restarted it and now get errors on this certificate: HL v. 0.6. I double-checked and have the same certificate still showing at cp-web github. Maybe the certificate has expired? Maybe stricter enforcement on Bluemix now disallows self-signed certificates?

> 2017-06-21T10:18:35.54-0400 [APP/0] OUT   msg: 'Certificate has not
>   been signed by a trusted authority. [x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification
>   failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate
>   "eca")]' }
>
> 2017-06-21T10:18:17.32-0400 [APP/0] OUT chain_setup.js Deployment
>   request:
>   {"fcn":"init","args":["IGNORE","ME"],"chaincodePath":"chaincode/","certificatePath
>   ":"/certs/peer/cert.pem"}

Answer (score 0):

When using Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1, certificates expire after 90 days.  There is an Hyperledger Fabric [issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1996) that documents that certificates are only valid for this length of time.  This issue indicates that there are not plans to change this for Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1.

When using Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1, the administrator of the blockchain network would have to take action to renew the certificates.  When the blockchain network is running on Bluemix, a support ticket should be opened and an administrative action can be taken to renew the certificates.

After renewing certificates, the user will need to run a query or invoke of the chaincode from every peer so the chaincode will start.  The chaincode stops during the certificate renewal process since the peers have to be restarted.